# Check if a string of chars is all comprised in another string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me why this piece of code doesn't return any values when there are matches from my table?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_AllEmployeesAndTownsWhichContainLetters(@setOfLetters NVARCHAR(200), @string NVARCHAR(200))
    RETURNS BIT 
        AS
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE @length INT, @i INT
            SET @length = LEN(@string)
            SET @i = 1      
            WHILE (@i < @length)
                BEGIN
                    IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@string, 1, @i),@setOfLetters) <= 0
                        RETURN 0
                    ELSE
                        SET @i = @i + 1
                END
            RETURN 1
        END GO
```

Comment: well, what data is being passed to it?

Comment: a column [Firstname] from a table, the column has many nvarchar values & im trying to check if any of those strings match the @setOfLetters (no matter what the order of the letters is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_AllEmployeesAndTownsWhichContainLetters(@setOfLetters NVARCHAR(200), @string NVARCHAR(200))
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @length INT, @i INT
    SET @length = LEN(@string)
    SET @i = 1      
    WHILE (@i < @length)
        BEGIN
            IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@string, 1, @i),@setOfLetters) > 0
                RETURN 1
            ELSE
                SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    RETURN 0
END
```